# How to combine two similar jQuery in header (scrollTo - smooth)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I managed to create scroll to effect on a testing web-page. At first I had

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
       'scrollTop':   $('#static').offset().top
              }, 1500);
});
})(jQuery);
```

which smoothly went on every page open to that anchor "static". Because header is big on page. so beside index page every navigation link would scroll past header down to anchor. That works perfect. But then I decided to make some submenu items. and they can't work because I use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){  
var str= location.hash; 
var n=str.replace("_temp","");
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(n).offset().top}, 500);
});
```

for that. This script can scroll down to anchor named "#something" on different page even and still smoothly scroll down. I found both scripts searching on Stack Overflow.

Problem is that when I use both of these, only 1st one works. They are similar so that's the problem. Is there any way to make them both work. If there is anchor "static" use first, if not use second?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$(document).ready(function(e){  
    var str= location.hash; 
    var n=str.replace("_temp","");

    if(n != "static") {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(n).offset().top}, 500);
    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({ 'scrollTop':   $('#static').offset().top}, 1500);
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm thnx m8 for reply.. it wont work :S it does work for the ones that are using "_temp" in name.. but the ones with id static it wont go :S

Comment: or if you cant make a fiddle post examples of your location.hash, that way we can find a suitable padron to make it work